# Finding out number of <span> elements inside <td> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have with me a `<td>` element. I want to find out the number of `<span>` elements inside of it.
I feel the `children().length` should do this, but what kind of selector should I use as a parameter to the `children()` method? Is there any other way using jquery/javascript to do so?

One possible example:

```
<td><span>*content*</span> &nbsp; <span>*content*</span> &nbsp;</td>
```

Here, I should have the answer as 2.

EDIT: I have a particular `<td>` element inside which I'm searching for the `<span>`.
So, it should be this,right:

```
$(td 'span').length
```

Comment: check my edited answer you can achieve the same thing with the children() function and you are doing wrong you need sector ("td > span") see my answer

Comment: @PranayRana: yeah the second part with children() method works too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get count of `span`, immediate child of `td`:

```
$('td > span').length;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UN3R2/1/)**

Read about **[$("parent > child") selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**

**According to your edit**

if `td` is a variable that contains the particular `<td>` reference like;

```
var td = $('td.some');
```

then you should try

```
$('span', td).length;
```

To point out a particular `td` element you should use `class` or `id` of that `td`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) - try this will work for you

See [`.length`](http://jsfiddle.net/UXT2E/).

```
alert($("td > span").length);
```

or

```
alert($('td').children('span').length );
```

#### Working Demo